# Trying to use xdebug on vim

Tags: vim, xdebug

I'm trying to use xdebug with vim on linux. I follow the [instructions](https://mutelight.org/minimal-guide-to-debugging-php-with-xdebug-and-vim) to install xdebug and after that I can see the information about xdebug if I call phpinfo() from a file inside the apache server.

After open a file in vim, it is supposed that when I press F5 it should show something like "waiting for a new connection on port 9000 for 10 seconds...", but it doesn't show anything..

Any idea?

Comment: What works and what doesn't? Did you install the vim plugin? Do you work locally?

Comment: It may sound obvious, but did you install the vim plugin for xdebug?

Comment: @el.atomo no, didn't install any more..:) After googling, I found two plugins. What of them shuld I install?: https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMarcWeber%2Fvim-addon-xdebug&ei=bcyYUMOuD-KY0QWo9oDwDQ&usg=AFQjCNG4suu_pk3Eknji1v6gFx7HsdeYKA https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FludovicPelle%2Fvim-xdebug&ei=bcyYUMOuD-KY0QWo9oDwDQ&usg=AFQjCNEVFBMoGgBNbUt5S1DCNw_8c9Z79A

Comment: Did you really follow that tutorial? I don't think so because there's a link to a specific plugin in the "Client-side" chapter. That's where the `<F5>` mapping is defined. Install the plugin, follow the tutorial *for real, this time* and come back if and when something doesn't work.

Comment: @tirengarfio, try the second one (https://github.com/ludovicPelle/vim-xdebug)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend you look at a new vim debugger plugin, called vdebug: https://github.com/joonty/vdebug -- it is actively developed and seems very capable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sort of problem, it turned out that my terminal emulator was capturing the  keypress and not sending it to vim (I think). Remapping the functions to different keys solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could actually be his/her keyboard.  If the keyboard has mult-media functions as well as F1-F12 on them... then there is, usually a "F-Lock" key next to the row of function keys that will turn on/off the function key behavior.  Really annoying, IMHO, for the new keyboards sold these days.... and rarely does the keyboard have a light to indicate the ulterior operation of said function keys.

I say this cuz, that is exactly what happened to me just now.